# GDAL/OGR Error: Cyclic VRT opening detected

Tags: gdal, ogr, attribute-joins, vrt

GDAL 2.2.4 (64bit Windows) throws an error during opening of a cyclic OGRVRT file.

There was no problem with cyclic VRTs in GDAL 1.10.1 (32bit Windows).

Here is a sample VRT file, which I used to join an ORACLE table with a MSSQL table:

```
<!-- file: myJoin.ovf -->
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="mssql">
        <SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="1">mssql.ovf</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbNone</GeometryType>
        <SrcSQL>SELECT * from mssql</SrcSQL>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="oracle">
        <SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="1">oracle.ovf</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <SrcLayer>oracle</SrcLayer>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="myJoin">
        <SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="1">myJoin.ovf</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <SrcSQL dialect="sqlite">
        SELECT o.*,m.ui_status from oracle o left join mssql m on o.uwi = m.ui
        </SrcSQL>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

ogrinfo (GDAL 2.2.4) throws an error:

```
D:\data>ogrinfo -ro myJoin.ovf
INFO: Open of `myJoin.ovf'
      using driver `OGR_VRT' successful.
1: MSSQL (None)
2: ORACLE (Point)
3: MYJOINERROR 1: Cyclic VRT opening detected !
 (None)
```

Is there any mechanism/flag, that prevents the "Cyclic VRT" detection and allows to use cyclic VRT files again?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly this feature was removed as part of a security fix in GDAL 2.2.2 ~ https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/Release/2.2.2-News (OGR_VRT: avoid crash on cyclic VRT).

For those looking at an alternative method, you can chain together your VRT datasources like below:

```
<!-- file: myJoinSources.ovf -->
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="mssql">
        <SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="1">mssql.ovf</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbNone</GeometryType>
        <SrcSQL>SELECT * from mssql</SrcSQL>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="oracle">
        <SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="1">oracle.ovf</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <SrcLayer>oracle</SrcLayer>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>

<!-- file: myJoin.ovf -->
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="myJoin">
        <SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="1">myJoinSources.ovf</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <SrcSQL dialect="sqlite">
        SELECT o.*,m.ui_status from oracle o left join mssql m on o.uwi = m.ui
        </SrcSQL>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

Comment: That‘s the workaround I already know. But sorry, this was not the question.

Comment: @christoph for a definitve answer you'd probably be better off contacting the developers directly, or posting an issue ~ https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/